# In Andromeda, S3E1 (If the Wheel is Fixed), how did Harper re-open the tunnel to the other universe?

Tags: andromeda

In the last episode of Andromeda's season 2 (Tunnel at the End of the Light), alien beings from another universe attack Andromeda (and the nascent Commonwealth) through a trans-universal tunnel.  In that episode Harper explicitly states that the aliens are using the entire power of a whole galaxy harnessed over 10,000 years to power their tunnel.  At the end of this episode Tyr and Becka destroy the aliens' machine... presumably setting the aliens back 10,000 years in their invasion plans (plus another galaxy's worth of energy).  But in the first episode of the third season, Harper builds a handheld device that reopens the tunnel without apparently even taxing the energy reserves of the Andromeda --- much less requiring all of the energy of an entire galaxy harnessed over 10,000 years...  So, where did Harper get so much energy to re-open the tunnel? Or, if he had no access to so much energy, how did he reopen the tunnel?